# redirect to app using an external payment service

Tags: c#, api, maui, payfast

I have created a dot net maui app. I'm using an external payment service called payfast.

When I want to make a transaction it directs me to a different page on the browser where I make my transactions. When the transactions are complete, I need to redirect back to the maui app.

The issue is that the service does not allow maui's url for example "myapp://". I get an error 400 bad request. "return_url: The return url format is invalid"

I tried to let it redirect to my API which is successful, but then I can't redirect the API back to my app

I have tried both return RedirectToPage("myapp://") and Request.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("myapp://") but it does not redirect back to my app

Comment: is your apps custom url scheme registered with the OS?

Comment: It is yes, in the mainactivity class I have registered it there: DataScheme = CALLBACK_SCHEME)]
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    const string CALLBACK_SCHEME = "myapp";
}

Comment: According to [this case which has the similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49857050/http-302-redirect-to-deep-link-does-not-work-in-android), the cause seems to be the browser.

Comment: @EtiennevanHeerden Did you find any solution to the issue? Are using webview for the external payment gateway?